# passing \n from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

I finally overcame the problem of passing full `utf-8` strings from javascript to python, but now the carriage return `"\n"` which is present on the Javascript side is missing when the string is received in python.  Is there something I'm supposed to do to achieve this?

```
function saveMeetingComments(){
    var komments = $('#cmt_t').val()
    var d = new Date();
    var commentsText  = $('#cmt_t').val()
    var abc = ''
    var request = par_makeHttpObject();
    commentsText = stringTranslate(commentsText,"'",'`');
    request.open("POST", "saveMeetingNote?clientID="+clid_+
             "&co_ID="+coid_+
             "&msgDate="+dateFormat(d, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM TT")+
             "&MeetType="+AGM_+
             "&MeetDate="+meetdate+"-"+
             "&Comments="+commentsText , false);
    request.send();
    $('#cmt_t').val('');
    parkAll();
}
```

Comments is the only variable which may have carriage returns.  On the Python side the code is as follows:

```
def saveMeetingNote(self, **kwargs):
    clientID         = kwargs['clientID']
    co_ID            = kwargs['co_ID']
    MessageDate      = kwargs['msgDate']
    MeetingType      = kwargs['MeetType']
    MeetingDate      = kwargs['MeetDate']
    Comments_        = kwargs['Comments']
    coName = dennislib.CompanyCoID2NAME(co_ID)[0]['FName']
    ret = dennislib.saveMeetingNotes(clientID,co_ID,MessageDate,MeetingType,MeetingDate,Comments_,coName)
    return 
saveMeetingNote.exposed = True
```

Inspecting Comments_ shows that the `\n` are all gone...

TIA

Dennis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're not URL-encoding the data before sticking it in the POST request URL. Newlines aren't the only thing which could be lost. What happens when someone types an `&` in the comment field?

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to fix this:

```
// ...
"&Comments=" + encodeURIComponent(commentsText)    // ...
```

On the server side, to decode this use:

```
import urllib
# ...
Comments_ = urllib.unquote(kwargs['Comments']).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: How do you decode it in Python...  Is there a function like decodeURIComponent?

Comment: Since this ends up in kwargs as separated elements, there is no need to do this to all the parts... is there???

Comment: @DKean: Ah, [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/946170/21475)! :-) Use `urllib.unquote(kwargs['Comments']).decode('utf-8')`. Regarding your second comment, it's generally a good idea to always escape (and therefore unescape on the server side) *everything*, just in case. But in your case, if you're sure the only URL variable that could contain invalid characters (all user input falls under this category) is the comment text, then you can encode/decode just that.

Comment: I do not have a "lib" in my Python install.  Where do I get this library?  Newbee

Comment: @DKean: Sorry, my fault. I somehow erased the 'url' part while typing the comment; it's `urllib`

Comment: @Cameron...  Okay, is that urllib supposed to be on the server?  I don't have that one either!

Comment: @DKean: Yes, on the server (you asked how to decode it in Python). [`urllib` is a standard Python module](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html). Did you `import` it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` on all of the variables before you concatenate them into your POST request.