# Is there a Javascript equivalent to urllib.quote and urllib.unquote?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, urllib

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618858/2134237) given to an identical question several years ago, encodeURIComponent(str) in Javascript should be equivalent to urllib.quote(str, safe='~()*!.\'') in Python.  By extension, I would have guessed that decodeURIComponent(str) would be equivalent to urllib.unquote(str).

This is not the case from my experience.  I'm writing some networking code to communicate from a Python server to a client on a website and I'm getting different results.

I'm generating a unique ID and sending it over TCP using something almost identical to the following code:

```
import urllib
import struct
import random

def sendID():
    id = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(128)
    upper = id >> 64
    lower = id & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    packed = struct.pack('<B2Q', 0x00, upper, lower)
    encoded = urllib.quote(packed, safe='~()*!.\'')

    # the below line is just sending it over an already established TCP connection
    # the code is irrelevant as I already this is working as expected
    sendtoclient(encoded)
```

The message is received on the clientside in the following websocket object callback:

```
this.websocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg.data);
    var sType = bufferpack.unpack('<B', decodeURIComponent(msg.data).substring(0, 1));
    console.log(sType);
};
```

This should decode the msg.data string and set sType to the first 'part' of the packed data (in this case 0x00).

The problem I'm encountering is that these functions are not working how I expected.  After some testing in JSFiddle and the Python command line, I am getting different results for the encode/decodeURIComponent and the urllib.quote/unquote functions.  encodeURIComponent just gives me a different result from the 'equivalent' urllib.quote, and decodeURIComponent results in a malformed URI error.

This can be seen in the sample shown below:

```
>>> import random
>>> import urllib
>>> import struct

>>> id = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(128)
>>> upper = id >> 64
>>> lower = id & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>>> packed = struct.pack('<B2Q', 0x00, upper, lower)
>>> encoded = urllib.quote(packed, safe='~()*!.\'')

>>> id
79837607446780471980532690349264559028L
>>> upper
4328005371992213727L
>>> lower
4092443888854326196L
>>> packed
'\x00\xdf\x08\x94\x7f\xf4)\x10<\xb4[a\xc2\x08H\xcb8'
>>> encoded
'%00%DF%08%94%7F%F4)%10%3C%B4%5Ba%C2%08H%CB8'
```

However when I use encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent on 'packed' and 'encoded' respectively I get a different encoded value and the decoding throws an error.  The Javascript followed by the output is shown below.

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent('\x00\xdf\x08\x94\x7f\xf4)\x10<\xb4[a\xc2\x08H\xcb8'))
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%00%DF%08%94%7F%F4)%10%3C%B4%5Ba%C2%08H%CB8'));
```

> %00%C3%9F%08%C2%94%7F%C3%B4)%10%3C%C2%B4%5Ba%C3%82%08H%C3%8B8
>   (index):50 Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

[JSFiddle snippet with the above Javascript code for your convenience](https://jsfiddle.net/h1w55Lug/).

So finally, my actual question: are the functions used above (quote/unquote and encode/decodeURIComponent) actually equivalent?  If not can somebody suggest code changes or other libraries/functions that could do what I'm expecting (the encoded/decoded and packed/unpacked value being the same on both client and server side)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around some more with my example code and reading some other resources about similar issues I found that the 'packed' string was encoded using the 'latin-1' character set and that urllib.quote was not working properly with that.

Below I've included the same example from my python interpreter with a few extra lines showing that with the proper encoding the functions urllib.quote/unquote and encode/decodeURIComponent are in fact equivalent when dealing with utf-8.

```
>>> import random
>>> import urllib
>>> import struct

>>> id = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(128)
>>> upper = id >> 64
>>> lower = id & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>>> packed = struct.pack('<B2Q', 0x00, upper, lower)
>>> encoded = urllib.quote(packed, safe='~()*!.\'')

>>> id
79837607446780471980532690349264559028L
>>> upper
4328005371992213727L
>>> lower
4092443888854326196L
>>> packed
'\x00\xdf\x08\x94\x7f\xf4)\x10<\xb4[a\xc2\x08H\xcb8'
>>> encoded
'%00%DF%08%94%7F%F4)%10%3C%B4%5Ba%C2%08H%CB8'

>>> packed.decode('latin-1')
u'\x00\xdf\x08\x94\x7f\xf4)\x10<\xb4[a\xc2\x08H\xcb8'
>>> packed.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
'\x00\xc3\x9f\x08\xc2\x94\x7f\xc3\xb4)\x10<\xc2\xb4[a\xc3\x82\x08H\xc3\x8b8'
>>> urllib.quote(packed.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8'), safe='~()*!.\'')
'%00%C3%9F%08%C2%94%7F%C3%B4)%10%3C%C2%B4%5Ba%C3%82%08H%C3%8B8'
```

The output

> '%00%C3%9F%08%C2%94%7F%C3%B4)%10%3C%C2%B4%5Ba%C3%82%08H%C3%8B8'

matches what was output by

> encodeURIComponent('\x00\xdf\x08\x94\x7f\xf4)\x10<\xb4[a\xc2\x08H\xcb8')

in Javascript.